# C++, How to implement Thread pool for tasks when each worker thread has to do few different tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I am analyzing a video stream. For each new image (frame) i do the following 3 tasks sequentially:

1. Reduce the size of the image
2. Detect faces
3. Track the 4 most important faces in the image

In order to speed this up on a 4-cpu machine I use 4 worker threads. In the following way

1. Main process gets an image. Creates 4 worker threads, split the image to 4 quarters, each worker re-sizes its 1/4 of the image pixels. Main process waits for the threads to finish and assembles the quarters to final image
2. Main process creates 4 new workers for face detection. I detect 4 types of faces (male, female, baby, dog). Each worker thread is responsible for one type. Main process waits for the workers to finish and assembles the results (list of all the existing faces).
3. Main process creates 4 new workers for face tracking. 4 most important faces are selected and each worker tracks 1 face. Main process waits for completion.

The problem with my implementation is that I don't have a thread pool. On each video frame (roughly 30 times per second) the main process rises and kills 12 workers (4 workers x 3 different tasks). So a lot of time is wasted on thread management. Currently I use `_beginthreadex()` method to lunch a worker thread for a specific task

**Desired solution:** I want to create only once 4 worker threads (each worker is able to perform all 3 different tasks). Those workers will exists through out the entire video processing. On each video frame the main process will throw the image re-size task to the workers, than the detection and later the tracking.

**An ugly implementation** would be that each worker thread is a big function with implementation of all the 3 tasks. Main process just tells each worker which task to execute (worker has a 'switch' statement to select the requested task). This is an ugly solution because in the future when I will have 30 different tasks in the pipeline instead of 3 - the code of the workers will become enormous. Moreover this solution violates encapsulation rule because it requires all the tasks to reside in the same function + for each new task, I need to change the code of the worker

**A clean implementation** would be that main process gives each worker a pointer to a function (which task to execute) and some parameters. Thus I can easily add new tasks in my video processing pipeline without changing the code of the worker because the code of the worker is generic (execute a pointer to a function and wait until a request with new pointer arrives)
But the problem here is that each task has a different amount of parameters (different function interface) and worker does not know how to call/execute the address of a given function.

What is a good way to use a thread pool in my case, while keeping code generic as possible, and able to extend it from 3 tasks to 30.

P.s. - My code runs on any platform (Android, iOS, linux, windows server, windows phone, etc). So I prefer a generic solution, instead of an OS specific or compiler specific solution

Comment: Are you using a c++11 compliant compiler ? Can you use any libraries like boost ? `std::async` uses thread pool under the hood I believe.

Comment: If you will divide whole image into 4 parts it is possible that your interested face might be broken up into 2 or 3 or worst case 4 images and i guess non of your thread would choose that broken face as face? and you might end up with bad result, don't you?

Comment: Thanks. The division of the image is roughly to 1/4 but not exactly. I already take care of the borders and stitch area to avoid such problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're too focused on using *functions*.

An old-fashioned approach is to have a base class `Task` with a member function `virtual void operator()();`. Then for anything that should be a task, you make a subclass of `Task` that contains all of the relevant data needed to run and provides an appropriate override of `operator()`.

A more modern approach would be to make tasks instances of `std::function<void(void)>` which not only works with the above approach, but for those cases where you actually have a function with that signature as well as with lambdas. (or since you're doing multithreading, maybe want something like `std::packaged_task<void(void)>`; I haven't really looked into how these are used)

Either way, once your worker threads obtain a reference to a task, they simply invoke `task();` to perform the task.

Comment: How does this help to achieve the thread pool OP is looking for ? `std::package_task` is an asynchronous task and doesn't have anything to do with thread pool.

Comment: Thanks. I did not use std::function<> but I will change all the prototypes to int (\*funcPtr)(void\* ParamsStruct), thus avoiding the need for std::function and creating a generic API